# how can I change text to tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
  <text
                        style={{
                          letterSpacing: '30',
                          wordBreak: 'keep-all',
                        }}
                      >
                        {value.content}
                      </text>
```

I got text from api data
content is text
How can I change pls help me 
plz check page picture [page picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AxXB.png)

Comment: Please check these official guidelines "How do I ask a good question?": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering API content with just text now.

try this `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={value.content} />`